# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) karma-test-shim.js:31

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm getting error when I perform  the command `npm run test`  from ubuntu in angular2 project. but the same project working fine in Mac os. Any idea about this?

Any help appreciated.